# Failed to start the Kernel error in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

Failed to start the Kernel.

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"c:'.
```

I am trying to run a line of code in VS Code, but it keeps throwing the error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.